# Filter expression for DynamoDB in Lambda for substring

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am having a filter expression in a Lambda function for DynamoDB as follows:

```
'FilterExpression': Attr('taskStatus').eq('NEW')
```

Here `taskStatus` is the attribute of the ddb.

I want to update it such that instead of equals it is changed to something like contains. Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

This is how it is done with python (boto3) and should be similar

```
table.scan(FilterExpression=Attr('column_name').contains('column_value'))
```